# Generating full (all sizes) combinations of arrays

Tags: javascript, combinations, cartesian-product

How to generate fully combinations of multiple arrays?

```
const source = [ ["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"] ];
const result = combination(source);
```

Need result, like a cartesian product, but with combinations of all sizes:

```
["a"]
["a", "d"]
["a", "d", "g"]
...
["b"]
...
["b", "f", "i"]
...
["i"]
```

Comment: what you have tried mate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function cartesianProduct(arrArr) {
  if (arrArr.length === 0) return [];

  const [firstArr, ...restArrs] = arrArr;
  const partialProducts = cartesianProduct(restArrs || []);

  let ret = firstArr.map(elem => [elem]);
  ret = ret.concat(partialProducts);
  ret = ret.concat(partialProducts.reduce((acc, product) => {
    return acc.concat(firstArr.map(elem => [elem].concat(product)));
  }, []));

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what is needed!